# How can I deactivate a kernel option?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I want to deactivate a kernel option during my build:

In a .bbappend file for the kernel recipe I fetch via `SRC_URI` a .cfg kernel fragment file `no_usb.cfg` with this content:

```
CONFIG_USB=n
CONFIG_USB_TEST=y
```

The first entry is supposed to turn USB off in the kernel configuration, the second entry is for testing the reverse case.

This didn't work: Neither the test entry appeared nor the USB was deactivated. I have also seen in the yocto sources *.scc files and I created one for my `no_usb.cfg`:

```
kconf hardware no_usb.cfg
```

But I found only less in the documentation and couldn't turn USB off. So how can I deactivate `CONFIG_USB`?

This is my kernel recipe (from freescale SDK) `linux-qoriq_3.12.bb`:

```
require recipes-kernel/linux/linux-qoriq.inc
SRC_URI = "git://git.freescale.com/ppc/sdk/linux.git;branch=sdk-v1.9.x"
SRCREV = "43cecda943a6c40a833b588801b0929e8bd48813"
```

I have a layer with this append file `linux-qoriq_3.12.bbappend`:

```
SRC_URI += "file://no_usb.cfg"
```

The directory structure of the layer is following:

```
meta-layer
└── recipes-kernel
    └── linux
        ├── linux-qoriq
        │   └── no_usb.cfg
        └── linux-qoriq_3.12.bbappend
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your kernel recipe had the following line

```
require recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto.inc
```

a SRC_URI referencing a `.cfg` should work.

However, the way to disable a kernel option is not to set it to `=0`. Rather, it should be set to

```
# CONFIG_USB is not set
```

In other words, that's the line you should have in your `.cfg` file. Also, make sure that you don't have contradicting options in the `.cfg` file.

Update:

Note again that this requires that your kernel recipe includes the line

```
require recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto.inc
```

in order to have the yocto kernel tooling working. As far as I can see from [meta-fsl-ppc: linux-qoriq.inc](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-fsl-ppc/tree/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-qoriq.inc) this recipe doesn't include that line.

Update:
See kergoth's answer, it is actually possible to use `.cfg` files in `linux-qoriq`. You just need to name them in the `DELTA_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG` variable.

Comment: It didn't work although I have everything like in your answer. I have the highest priority in my layer, but is it overwritten maybe? Furthermore the test option isn't there.

Comment: Could you show is your layer? Or at least the cfg file and the recipe?

Comment: I mixed  `linux-yocto.inc` and `linux-qoriq.inc`. So there is no way to edit kernel options? When I require `linux-yocto.inc` in my append file, there are errors

Comment: Well, you can supply your own `defconfig`, that's the normal way. But, no, there's no way out-of-the-box to use `.cfg` and `.scc` files i `linux-qoriq`.

Comment: Ok thanks for you answer. Then i will use an own defconfig for now and somewhen migrate to the "normal" linux-yocto if this will be possible.

Answer (score 5):

As was stated by the previous commenter, you need to use `# CONFIG_FOO is not set` rather than `CONFIG_FOO=n`. I would like to make one correction, though. The linux-qoriq recipe *does* support configuration fragments, it just uses a separate variable to control their usage, `DELTA_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG`. See the `do_configure_prepend` in `recipes-kernel/linux/linux-qoriq.inc` for details.

In your append, you should be able to add this to fix it:

```
DELTA_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG += "no_usb.cfg"
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I never looked that thoroughly. Hm, had I had a board based on the qoriq, I would have looked into replacing that part with the standard mechanism.

Comment: I wonder why this variable does not appear when I type `bitbake -e`. Furthermore I eventually got it working when I looked closer at `linux-qoriq.inc `. There are two casis in it: `if [ -f "${deltacfg}" ]; then` and `elif [ -f  "${S}/arch/${ARCH}/configs/${deltacfg}" ]; then`. I dont't understand the first one. Where do I have to place the file, that it is fetched by the code?

Comment: When a file is listed in SRC_URI, it gets placed into WORKDIR by do_unpack. It sounds like they must have altered the logic recently, as the current meta-fsl-ppc has a second clause in that if statement: `elif [ -f "${WORKDIR}/${deltacfg}" ]; then`, which covers this use case. It sounds like it won't work out of the box with the version you're using, unless you were to alter the entry in SRC_URI to place it into `${S}/arch/${ARCH}/configs`, i.e. `file://no_usb.cfg;subdir=git/arch/${ARCH}/configs`, if `S` in the recipe is `${WORKDIR}/git`. (subdir= is relative to WORKDIR).

Comment: `DELTA_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG` works for me as well with a kernel for the LS1046A. Seems to be a QorIQ thing.